# RJMP implementation in assembler, avr

Tags: c, assembly, project

I'm doing my project. It's virtual processor implemented in C language. The problem is, that RJMP don't want to work properly. 
Here is C implementation:

```
void F_JMP_REL(void){
printf("0x%04X[0x%04X]: JMP PC+0x%04X\n", getPC(), getOpcode(), getOpcode() & 0x0FFF);

if((getOpcode() & 0x0800)==0)
    setPC(getPC()+(getOpcode() & 0x0FFF));
else
    setPC(getPC()-(0x1000-(getOpcode() & 0x0FFF)));

addCounter(1);
}
```

And here is assembler instruction:

```
.text
.global    main
.type    main, @function

main:
ldi r30, 0x00
mov r3, r1
mov r4, r2
rjmp 
ldi r16, 0x00
ldi r16, 0x01
ldi r17, 0x32
```

I want rjmp to jump straight to first instruction in first case, and to for e.g. ldi r17, 0x32. IDK why, but when I'm typing addres 2K+1, so K=1 so in hex it will be 0x001, it don't work and jumps to 0x07FB. I tried $+2, but error occurs in avr compiler

Comment: What binary opcode does the `rjmp` instruction have after you assemble?

Comment: By the way: You can get rid of the `if`: `setPC(getPC()+(getOpcode() & 0x07FF)-(getOpcode() & 0x0800));`